# How to install python module into dist-packages directory directly?

Tags: python-3.x, module, package

I build a package in /tmp.

```
tree myanalyse
myanalyse
├── myanalyse
│   ├── ana.py
│   ├── __init__.py
├── README.md
└── setup.py
```

Install it locally.

```
cd  /tmp/myanalyse
sudo python3 setup.py build
sudo python3 setup.py install
```

Now check it.

```
import  myanalyse
print(myanalyse.__path__)
['/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/myanalyse-0.1-py3.5.egg/myanalyse']
```

Normally,when you install a  module such as `pandas` in your python ,there must be a directory `pandas` in `/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages`.

```
import pandas
print(pandas.__path__)
['/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/pandas']
```

It is `/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/myanalyse-0.1-py3.5.egg/myanalyse` ,not `/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/myanalyse` in my python,how can i install this package `myanalyse` in the format `/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/myanalyse` ,instead of `/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/myanalyse-0.1-py3.5.egg/myanalyse` ?

Comment: Can you add the contents of `setup.py`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use:

```
python3 setup.py install --single-version-externally-managed --root=/
```

or you could also force a non-egg build with:

```
python3 setup.py install --old-and-unmanageable
```

From the [docs](https://packaging.python.org/guides/distributing-packages-using-setuptools/#configuring-your-project):

> Note When installing packages as egg, data_files is not supported. So, if your project uses setuptools, you must use pip to install it. Alternatively, if you must use python setup.py, then you need to pass the --old-and-unmanageable option.